# How to do area-weighted regridding of regular lat-lon data using python

Tags: python, interpolation

I would like to be able to perform area-weighted regridding of regularly spaced 2D latitude-longitude data in python, e.g. from a 0.5x0.5 grid to a 2.5x3.75 grid for example. This data is emissions in kg/m^2/s, so I will need to conserve mass as well as the spatial distribution.

I know that there are a number of scipy interpolation routines, and I am unsure which, if any, would be the best one to use in this case. I would prefer not to have to install too many extra python packages if possible, unless absolutely required (i.e. I have scipy+numpy installed, but would rather not have to install a specialist python package which, will doing what I need, also requires me to store the data in a particular class structure etc. However, I will do this if needed!).

This is also a bit of a learning exercise for me to understand how to do these sorts of things in python, as well as being able to do it.

Comment: Is your data of the form: Lat, Lon, emission density value? ie. three numbers.. with the 0.5 being the spacing between adjacent latitude values say?

Comment: I have a 2 1D vectors defining the latitudes and longitudes. These are usually 0.5x0.5 or 1x1. For the 1x1 the lat is usually 181 points -90.0,-89.0,...,89.0,90.0, and for 0.5x0.5 this would usually be 360 points -89.75,-89.25,...,89.25,89.75 etc. 

The longitudes for 1x1 would be 360 points -180.0,-179.0,...178.0,179.0, and for 0.5x0.5 this would be 720 points 0.25,0.75,...,359.25,359.75.

Comment: These define the grid-cell centres. The grid I usually use is 73x96 (so-called N48); latitudes go from -90.0,-87.5,...,87.5,90.0 and the longitudes from 0.0,3.75,...,352.5,356.25. I also occasionally use a grid which is 1.25x1.875 (so-called N96).

The data is then held in a 2D array (latitude x longitude) and contains the emission flux in kg/m^2/s. I need to convert the data at the higher resolution into the courser resolution, while ensuring that the spatial distribution is (as much as possible) unchanged, while also keeping the total amount emitted the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a complex question, and the answer is fairly involved, and there is a lot of opportunity to go wrong. As you say in your comments, you have longitude, latitude vectors like this:

```
'0.5x0.5'
np.arange(-89.75,90.25,0.5)      #[-89.75,-89.25,...,89.25,89.75],  latitudes 
np.arange(0.25,360.25,0.5)       #[0.25,0.75,...,359.25,359.75],    longitudes
```

or this:

```
'1x1'
np.arange(-90.0,91.0,1.0)         #[-90.0,-89.0,...,89.0,90.0],     latitudes 
np.arange(-180.0,180.0,1.0)       #[-180.0,-179.0,...178.0,179.0],  longitudes
```

and you need to convert the associated data set to this format:

```
'73x96 (or N48)'
np.arange(-90.0,92.5,2.5)         #[-90.0,-87.5,...,87.5,90.0]      latitudes 
np.arange(0.0,360.00,3.75)        #[0.0,3.75,...,352.5,356.25]      longitudes
```

or this:

```
'1.25x1.875 (or N96)'
np.array(-90.0,91.25,1.25)        #[-90.0,-88.75,...,90.00]         latitudes 
np.array(0.0,360.00,1.875)        #[0.0,1.875,...,358.125]          longitudes
```

All entries are for grid cell centres.

The partially good news is that you don't need to do any interpolation. We can `upsample` (both longitudinally and latitudinally) just by repeating entries, i.e. if we have a `1*1` spaced data set we can change it to a `0.5*0.5` spaced data set, by repeating every column and row, this is valid for your data even though we are using spherical grid data! Think of dividing up one of your initial cells into smaller cells - the density is the same in every new cell as it was in the original cell. We can do that like this:

```
data_up = np.repeat(data, 2, axis=0)
data_up = np.repeat(data_up, 2, axis=1)
```

This is a good approach as we make no assumptions, and lose no data. We will need this later.

We can `downsample` when we increase the width of the cells longitudinally, by adding the cells together and averaging over the number of cells. This is due to the areas in longitudinally adjacent (horizontal) cells being equal. If we are `downsampling` to a grid spacing that is not an integer multiple of our original spacing, then first we have to `upsample`, as described above (this is a requirement for you..).

The trickiest thing to do is to downsample latitudinally. This is because here we have different densities and the actual areas associated with those densities are also different. The way to deal with this is:

1. Upsample to a new latitudinal grid spacing that is a multiple of our initial latitudinal grid and our desired latitudinal grid (as explained above).
2. Calculate the cell surface area for every cell ([this is the formula we need](https://badc.nerc.ac.uk/help/coordinates/cell-surf-area.html)).
3. Multiply these two arrays together to get the total emissions from every data cell in our upsampled data array.
4. Add together all the total emissions cells that make up a new cell (do this over the entire array)
5. Divide through by the total area for that new cell (the sum of all the areas for the sub cells), do this for all the new cells.
6. That's it.

**Bad things to be aware of:**

1. There are longitudinal phase differences between some of your data sets, this can be fiddly to ensure that you are repositioning the data correctly to allow for this.
2. The pole cells, where `latitude = 90 or -90`. These cells are problematic as they have half the latitudinal height as all the other cells. This has to be carefully allowed for: ensure that the areas calculated for these cells are correct, and also when/if upsampling, the `pole` entries should only be repeated half as much to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks fraxel - that's a really clear and helpful answer. Can I check one thing though - why isn't there an associated problem upsampling the latitudinal data as there is for downsampling? My first thought is that the problem exists in both directions.

Comment: Think of a single data cell (in the original data set). Every point within that cell has the same density (both lat and lon). So you can subdivide that cell as many times as you want (thus upsampling), and the density remains the same, without problem. But when it comes to the downsampling, we are no longer dividing the cell up - instead we are combining them, and averaging them, so we must weight them correctly by their area (which changes latitudinally). Drawing some pictures using [this kind of projection](http://bodengeo7.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/2236_ban.jpg) really helps visualise it.